# Python. Как реализовать двоичную кучу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как вообще она реализуется на практике?

Не нашел материала,где помимо теории показывались бы примеры её реализации.

К примеру:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я  понимаю,это просто куча,но не двоичная?

Еще такой вопрос,даже реализовав именно двоичную кучу,то как её можно приемлемым образом вывести?
К примеру,в таком виде:

0

1 2

3 4 5 6

Тут простой пример,вопрос про,например,случайный массив как у меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это именно двоичная min-куча.

Вывести можно после heapify слоями. сначала первый элемент списка, потом 2-3, потом 4-7 итд.
Должно получиться что-то похожее:

```py
              4
       7               9
   8      27      29      37
27  10  43
```

Свойства min-кучи такие:

1. Каждый узел должен быть ≥ своего родителя
2. Все слои дерева кроме последнего должны быть заполнены. В последнем должно быть заполнено как минимум начало слоя без пробелов.

Здесь эти свойства соблюдаются

Comment: А вообще,есть какой-то более автоматизированный способ? 
Чтобы можно было реализовать,к примеру,удаление и добавление элементов в кучу.

Comment: @Hikaharu все есть в модуле `heapq`: [`heapq.heappush`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappush), [`heapq.heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop) и т.д.

Comment: Я к тому,что я же вручную вывожу каждый слой. И при добавлении и удалении нужно будет каждый раз лезть в код и убирать/добавлять элементы в вывод.

Comment: @Hikaharu выводить нужно, разумеется, в цикле, пропорционально уменьшая расстояние между элементами на каждом слое. Если это для вас проблема, вы рано взялись за двоичные кучи.

Comment: Окей. Пойду пытаться реализовывать. 
Рано или нет,в любом случае выбор у меня невелик. Задание есть задание.
Python еще плохо знаю,т.к. с плюсов внезапно пришлось перейти.

Comment: Ну тогда это может помочь: `'{:^10}'.format(27)` :)